# How to select only paragraphs that contain certain child elements with nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have the following XML:

```
<w:p w14:paraId="07E73137" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidP="00D279DF" w:rsidR="00D279DF" w:rsidRDefault="00D279DF">
</w:p>
<w:p w14:paraId="07E73138" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidP="00D279DF" w:rsidR="00D279DF" w:rsidRDefault="00D279DF>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00922473">
      <w:t xml:space="preserve">Visual attributes </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:ins w:author="RKH RKH" w:date="2016-12-17T16:40:00Z" w:id="0">
        <w:r>
            <w:t>an</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:del w:author="RKH RKH" w:date="2016-12-17T16:40:00Z" w:id="1">
        <w:r w:rsidDel="008B2A6A">
          <w:delText>the</w:delText>
        </w:r>
    </w:del>
</w:p>
```

The first `<w:p>` element does not contain any `<w:ins>` and `<w:del>` children elements.
However, the second `<w:p>` does contain `<w:ins>` and `<w:del>` elements.

I am currently selecting all paragraph elements using the following:

```
@all_paragraph_nodes = @file.xpath('//w:p')
```

I would like to select only paragraph elements that contain at least one `<w:ins>` element or `<w:del>` element.

How can I do this using Nokogiri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
@all_paragraph_nodes = @file.xpath('//w:p[w:ins or w:del]')
```

Note that you have a typo in the 3rd lines of your XML :

```
w:rsidRDefault="00D279DF
```

isn't closed.

Comment: Thank you Eric. My bad for copying the code I left off the closed xml.